# Order of Summation in proof, Grimmett and Stirzaker 3.11.13.a

Tags: probability

The question asks to prove:

$E(X) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X>n)$

$E(X) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}mP(X=m) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}P(X=m) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}P(X=m) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(X>n)$

My only problem is understanding how the new limits when the summations are changed going from the 3rd to the 4th expression.

For example $P(x=0)$ is included in $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}P(X=m)$ but it doesn't seem to be included in $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}P(X=m)$?

Can someone explain this?

Comment: I don’t think $P(X=0)$ is included in the third expression.

Comment: In the third equality, they have used $m=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}1$.

Clearly, we have $0\le n\le m-1$ which also means $m\ge n+1, n\ge0$. 

Loosely speaking, the sums can be interchanged as long as they are convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the indicator

$$\mathbf{1}_{(n \leqslant m-1)} = \mathbf{1}_{(m \geqslant n+1)} = \begin{cases}1, & n \leqslant m-1\\0, & n > m-1 \end{cases}$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{m-1} P(X = m) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X = m) \mathbf{1}_{(n \leqslant m-1)} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X = m) \mathbf{1}_{(m \geqslant n+1)}\\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} P(X = m) \mathbf{1}_{(m \geqslant n+1)} \\ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty} P(X = m)  $$

We can interchange the sums in the second line by Tonelli's theorem since the terms are non-negative.

Comment: https://planetmath.org/TonellisTheorem : just as a reference to which theorem of Tonelli you are referring to. It may have been clear to many but not to (at least) me.

Comment: @DanishA.Alvi: Thank you for adding that reference.